Why does my app crash without error in the log?
I have to make an app for a project in university. I'm using Android Studio with Kotlin. This is my first time using Kotlin so it is quite new for me. The problem I have is that I want to make a menu in my app but when I write the code I experience an app crash without an error in the log. I don't know why this is happening I tried figuring out my error for the past two days and nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.
This is my code
MainActivity:
package com.example.medprojapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.Companion.installSplashScreen
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Thread.sleep(1500)
        installSplashScreen()


        drawerLayout = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout)

        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val navigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_nav, R.string.close_nav)
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home)
        }

    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.nav_home -> replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
            R.id.nav_settings -> replaceFragment(SettingsFragment())
            R.id.nav_share -> replaceFragment(ShareFragment())
            R.id.nav_logout -> Toast.makeText(this, "Logout!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        val transaction: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        }else{
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}

main layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/tuerkis"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/tuerkis"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/tuerkis"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

nav menu layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn = "navigation_view">

    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
            android:title="Home"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_settings_24"
            android:title="Settings"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_picture_as_pdf_24"
            android:title="Share"/>
    </group>

    <item
        android:title="">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/baseline_exit_to_app_24"
                android:title="Logout"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>


unfortunately not

And this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455645/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-no-error-logs-in-logcat

I tried to locate this on my Mac and I don't quite understand what it tells me
Edit: this log is for the whole computer as I understand or am I wrong?

You need to find the LogCat. That's the log on your android device where you execute the app. The first link I posted explains how to find it.

Oh ok I assumed you meant if there is no error in the LogCat. Because I do have an error message in the LogCat but I cannot figure out how to solve this error. It tells me that I should change to Theme.AppCompat but when I change this it either crashes or the splash screen is gone.
